# How to implement a REST API in Drupal for nested field collections

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to put together a headless Drupal 7 implementation around a content type with repeated nested data. I have no option but to use Drupal 7 vs Drupal 8 or a native headless CMS.

For example, consider a music album which could be modeled as an Album resource as:

```
{"title" : "Something Cool",
 "tracks" : [
    "track" : {
      "title": "Track 1", 
      "samples" : [
        {"file" : "/path/to/file"},
        {"file" : "/path/to/another/file"}
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

In D7, I can define a content type using some nested field collections to represent the repeating structures in the above and the Services module to expose that as a REST endpoint. The problem I have is that the Services api doesn't traverse into the field collection so I would be left with just a top level property for the tracks and no detail.

Is there a simple way to implement this using an alternate REST module or Services. I have seen one post that implemented a separate lookup for the field collection which is not ideal since that would result in several roundtrips for each

Comment: This could help with entity_reference fields (not collections but they should be similar) https://www.drupal.org/project/restws_entityreference. It should make a seprate sql query for each row of the main entity - thus cannot be ideal in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are serving REST using views. This module might help: [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view.).

It let's you embedd a view inside view. For your solutions, create a view X that serves field collection, with contextual filter of entity id. 
Embed view X into your main view.